# $\displaystyle\int_C (e^x+\cos(x)+2y)\,dx+(2x-\frac{y^2}{3})\,dy$ in an ellipse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I have to compute $\displaystyle\int_C (e^x+\cos(x)+2y)\,dx+(2x-\frac{y^2}{3})\,dy$ in the ellipsoide $\frac{(x-2)^2}{49}+\frac{(y-3)^2}{4}=1$ using Green's Theorem.

The first thing I did was getting the parametric equation of the ellipse.

$\alpha(t)=(2+7\cos(t),3+2\sin(t)),\; t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Now, I'm not sure if I have to replace in the function every $x$ and $y$ with the result I got, and then using (maybe) polar coordinates to finally compute the result. Is my approach correct?

Comment: An ellipsoid is a surface. I guess you mean an ellipse. Now, if we call $$\mathbf{F}=\langle F_1,F_2\rangle=\langle e^x+\cos x+2y,2x-\tfrac{1}{3}y^2\rangle,$$ then you may use either $$\mathbf{F}=\nabla\left(e^x+\sin x+2xy - \tfrac{1}{9}y^3\right)$$ together with the fundamental theorem of calculus, or $$\operatorname{rot}\mathbf{F}=\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}=0$$ together with the Green's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the gradient of $$f(x,y)=e^x+\sin(x)+2xy-\frac{y^3}{9}$$ is the vector field $$\bigg<e^x+\cos(x)+2y,2x- \frac{y^3}{3} \bigg>$$ This means your vector field is conservative, so its integral over any closed curve (like your **ellipse**, not ellipsoid) is zero. With Green's Theorem, $$\int_{C}\vec{\nabla} f \cdot d\vec{r}=\int \int _{R} 0\cdot dA=0$$ Here $C$ is your ellipse and $R$ is its interior.

Comment: If you know that the vector field comes from a potential function $f$, then one do not need Green's Theorem at all.

Comment: Of course, but the OP said they had to use Green's Theorem, so I threw it in there along with some other useful information

Comment: That makes much more sense! Sorry I missed that part :)

Comment: Great! I see it now, I meant ellipse sorry. Thank you all